# Returning a String with values included between two in parameters in java

Tags: java

I have a method which has two `int` parameters and I need to return a `String` which contains the values between the first integer and the second integer.

```
static String Q2(int start, int stop) {

    return "";
}
```

I start with the `start` number and then print all numbers up too `stop` but I have to return a number (as String). Lets suppose the `int start` was 15 and `stop` was 20. Then, it would have to print `151617181920`, and the whitespace does not matter

Comment: First you say you have to return a `String` and then you say you have to return a type `int`.

Comment: `String which contains the values between the first integer and the second integer.` What does this entail? Is `start` itself included? How about `stop`? What's the string format? Is it delimited by spaces, commas, etc.? Can you give us an example input and its correct output?

Comment: means you want to print 456 if start number is 3 and stop number is 7.

Comment: There was a typo you have to return a string and lets suppose the int start was 15 and stop was 20. Then, it would have to print 151617181920 and the whitespace does not matter

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String inbetween(int start, int stop)
{
    String result = "";

    for(int i = start; i <= stop; i++)
    {
        result += String.valueOf(i);
    }

    // return Integer.parseInt(result); // To return as an int
    return result;
}
```

I'm assuming this is just a simple code challenge kind of question, but otherwise you would probably want to return an `int[]` or `String[]` so you can parse the numbers more easily.

Alternatively with Java 8 streams:

```
public static String inbetween(int start, int stop)
{
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(start, stop).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining()); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks I know how to use the arrays for this but I wanted to know how to use this approach where you can return a string

Answer (score 0):

Use Below method for your problem.

```
 public String getNumbersBetween(int start, int stop)
    {
     StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = start; i < stop; i++)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```